# In Python 3.8+ is there a way to create a "named" type union?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I have a very long type union that I use in a number of places. I would like to name this union and use the name in place of the long list of types that make up the union.

In other words instead of writing this:

```py
def foo(self) -> Union[Foo, Bar, Fizz, Buzz, Splat, Bang, Woo, Wizz]:
    ...
```

I would like to write:

```py
def foo(self) -> MyUnion:
    ...
```

I googled around a bit and I am still not sure if this is a supported feature by the python typing package. If it is, maybe this question will help other fellow googlers who are trying to bind python unions to a variable / named type.

Comment: you want a type alias `Name = Union[...]`

Comment: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#type-aliases

Comment: Also, https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Python calls them "Type Aliases" and the docs can be found here: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#type-aliases